# Module variables don't survive CodeModule.InsertLines call

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to add a button to my worksheet during run-time. This button should just display different worksheet that is also created on  during run-time. I added button like this:

```
Dim btnShowTable
Set btnShowTable = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(rowRange.Left + 10, rowRange.Top + 10, rowRange.Width - 20, rowRange.Height - 20)
btnShowTable.Caption = "Show table data"
btnShowTable.OnAction = AddClickHandler_ShowSheet("ClickModule", "TableView", tableSheet)


Function AddClickHandler_ShowSheet(ByVal moduleName As String, ByVal btnName As String, ws As Worksheet)
  Dim methodName As String
  methodName = btnName & "_" & AddClickHandler_GetId() & "_Click"
  Dim LineNum As Long
  Dim VBCodeMod As CodeModule
  Set VBCodeMod = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(moduleName).CodeModule
  With VBCodeMod
    LineNum = .CountOfLines + 1
      .InsertLines LineNum, _
        "Sub " & methodName & "()" & Chr(13) & _
        "    " & ws.CodeName & ".Select" & Chr(13) & _
        "End Sub"
  End With
  AddClickHandler_ShowSheet = moduleName & "." & methodName
End Function
```

Function that creates the button is in one module while AddClickHandler_ShowSheet is in another.

The idea is that I would have separate module that would contain all these click handlers so that I could easily delete all of them.
This works ok. The handlers are created and buttons work as expected. The issue that I have is that, when this InsertLines method is called, all of my module variables in a module that contains the function for button creation are lost.
I have 4 module variables

```
Dim xmldoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument
Dim xmlDataMap() As DataNode
Dim xmlDataMapLast As Integer
Dim xmlTables As Collection
```

after a call to InsertLines all of them became empty except for xmlDataMapLast  which contains correct value of 14.

If I try to debug this method when I step over InserLines call I get an error "Can't enter break mode at this time." and I can't debug anything until my function ends. If I comment out the call to AddClickHandler_ShowSheet my variables remain intact, so it must be something related to that call.

Am I trying to achieve the impossible or am I just doing it the wrong way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's no surprise the module is reset.
In fact, I would expect value types to reset, too. It's a bit of surprise 
they survive.

Why would you need to store variables in the module you use for code generation?
Store them in a separate module and only use this module for code generation.

---

Having that said, why would you dynamically add code in the first place?
`OnAction` supports parameters:

```
Sub asdff()
  Worksheets(1).Buttons(1).OnAction = "'Module1.ParametrizedHandler 5, ""Hi there""'"
End Sub

Public Sub ParametrizedHandler(ByVal foo As Long, ByVal bar As String)
  MsgBox foo, vbInformation, bar
End Sub
```

Note the absence of parentheses in the call string, and the single quotes around it.

Comment: Thanks. You are a life saver.I didn't know that I could use parameters like this.

Comment: BTW. Button was generated in module A. Function that generated the handler was in a module B, and handler was placed in a module C. Variables were in a module A, so I didn't think that adding code in module C would affect them. Do you have any link that could clarify what actually happened a little bit?