# Losing Public Variables after Dynamically adding code

Tags: excel, vba

I hope my question will be clear enough for you problem solvers to understand :).

I am using VBIDE.VBproject in order to dynamically add code to my worksheets after creating one. To save you the Whole code i got i made a little test setup.

```
Public teller As Integer
Sub AddCode()
Debug.Print "Start running SUB Addcode"
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim xPro As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim xCom As VBIDE.VBComponent
    Dim xMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
    Dim xLine As Long
    Dim wsActive As String
    Dim wsindex As Integer
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    wsindex = ActiveSheet.Index
    wsActive = Worksheets(wsindex).CodeName
    
    With wb
        Set xPro = .VBProject
        Set xCom = xPro.VBComponents(wsActive)
        Set xMod = xCom.CodeModule

        With xMod
            xLine = .CreateEventProc("BeforeRightClick", "Worksheet")
xLine = xLine + 1
            .InsertLines xLine, "Dim Keuze As Integer"
        End With
End With
Debug.Print teller
Debug.Print "Finished running AddCode"
End Sub


Sub Countteller()
Debug.Print "Run Countteller"
teller = teller + 1

Debug.Print teller


End Sub
```

Basically what happens is that i trigger my "Countteller" sub a few times on order to store a Public Variable. Whenever i trigger the Sub "AddCode" i write a bit of code to "Sheet1". After that sub has finished running the Integer named "Teller" is still set to its pervious number. But as soon as i run the sub "Countteller" again. My public variable gets erased..

I know there is a way for me to just store this value in a cell, and then retrieve the cell whenever something triggers somewhere. Unfortunately the total scope of the project i m currently working on makes it though to do it this way and hide it properly.

De code had been place in "This workbook" i have tried placing it in modules as well or making Public subs, but nothing seems to work for me.

If anybody knows a workaround to this problem or a possible solution i would highly appricate it

Thanks in advance,

See Below my Debug window
[My Debug window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bk3cA.png)

Comment: Yes, the module is [supposed to reset](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6089178/11683).

Comment: Hey GSerg, i came across your article as well. But i don't quite fully understand how i could implement this for myself or if it would work for me.

Comment: Usually, if I want to have code in a Worksheet that needs to be created at runtime, I keep a Worksheet including the code as Template and rather that adding a worksheet, I just copy the template sheet.

Comment: @Merocky I doubt you could. I there offered an alternative solution to the [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147640) the OP was having, that did not require code generation. If your actual problem is that you need a `BeforeRightClick` handler on a dynamically generated sheet, then a possible solution is using a workbook-level [`Workbook_SheetBeforeRightClick`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.sheetbeforerightclick) instead.

Comment: @FunThomasThanks for the advice sofar. I started working on this document a few months ago. I remember having issues Copy and pasting sheets where some Functionallity of the complete document would fall off. Since i m more experienced in using VBA after making this document i might have to revisit copy and pasting these sheets. What i already make use of is make 2 SOURCE pages which i copy and paste. But only the excel content not the complete page. I had a reason for doing this back then but i cant remember.

Comment: @GSerg Unfortunatly Workbook_SheetBeforeRightClick isent working for me. My Code already takes some time to run because i m using a book wide "On calculate" and a bunch of other automatic triggers. The sheets that i generate have Different ranges for Rightclick triggers and would be a pain to make it all compatible and fast (under 0.2 sec preferable). For me the "easiest" would be if this issue i am having would have a workaround. What i can do is write my publics into a register on the users computer before adding code, but i prefer not do to so. I dont like messing with registers :(